# requests.get() not completing with Tiktok user profile

Tags: python, python-requests

So, basically, it seems that `requests.get(url)` can't complete with Tiktok user profiles url:

```
import requests
url = "http://tiktok.com/@malopedia"
rep = requests.get(url) #<= will never complete
```

As I don't get any error message, I have no idea what's going on. Why is it not completing? How do I get it to complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TikTok is quite strict when it comes to automated connections so you need to provide headers in your request, like this:

```
import requests

url = "http://tiktok.com/@malopedia"
rep = requests.get(
    url,
    headers={
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "Accept-Encoding": "identity;q=1, *;q=0",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US;en;q=0.9",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "Pragma": "no-cache",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0",
    },
)
print(rep)
```

This should respond with `200`.

However, if you plan on doing some heavy lifting with your code, consider using one of the unofficial API wrappers, like [this one](https://github.com/Daan-Grashoff/TikTok-Api).

Comment: Couldn't get any of them to work... I'd be downloading one video every few days, I don't think that's heavy lifting?

Comment: That should be fine, yeah :)